# Android SoundPool: AudioFlinger error

Tags: java, android, multithreading, soundpool

My SoundManager class uses SoundPool for it's audio. I have a sound that will loop, 1 second on and 2 seconds off until told to stop. The problem is that this will execute once and then I notice an error in logcat saying "SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack" and then "AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12" My code is below. Any idea why im getting this error?

```
public class SoundManager {

    public SoundManager(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        sp = new SoundPool(1,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        spSound = sp.load(mContext, R.raw.tone4402, 1);
    }
    public void Tone3(int timer) {
        (new Thread(t3)).start();
    }
    final Runnable t3 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(isPlaying == false) {
                isPlaying = true;
                Tone3Run();
            }
        }
    };
    public static void Tone3Run() {
        //1 sec on, 2 sec off, repeat for 2 minute
        Log.d("Sound", "Tone3 Playing");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long currentTime;
        do
        {
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.e("Sound Manager", "Time:" + (currentTime - startTime));
            temp = sp.play(spSound, currentVolume, currentVolume, 1, -1, (float)1.0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            sp.pause(temp);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while( ((currentTime - startTime) < 120000) && (boolStop = false) );
        sp.release();
        sp = new SoundPool(1, 4, 0);
        spSound = sp.load(mContext, R.raw.tone4402, 1);
        isPlaying = false;
}
```

Comment: `-12` is `ENOMEM`, or 'out of memory'. [Error Codes](http://www.barricane.com/c-error-codes-include-errno)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, was able to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

`Error : AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12`
belongs to the total number of active tracks are 32 and you are trying to create another track.
Android only can supports 32 tracks names.
Can you check other errors like `Obtain Buffer TimeOut`.
Please try your application to other Android device or check with reboot your device.